# Ipython has no attribute get_ipython() on debug mode only

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm, ipython

I'm having an issue in pycharm while running my debugger :
*"AttributeError: module 'IPython' has no attribute 'get_ipython'"*

The problem is that I don't know what IPython is, I'm not using it, and when i clink on the first link in the error log, I arrive in a file that is not even mine.

More, if I run my code without debugger, this error do not appear.

Here is the full trace :
[image]

It looks like this come from matplotlip but it doesn't really help me.

Thank you for any help

Comment: That bug is so annoying, need help there too....

Comment: Remade my conda environment and the error went away.. hmm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also very annoyed about this bug so I tried some stuff and found a workaround (not clean though...).

I work with venv environments so I just changed the file/code which throws the error.

Go to backend_bases.py. For me it's: \venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py. Or just click on the last stacktrace.

In line 1744 you find this code:

```
if sys.modules.get("IPython") is None:
    return
```

Change it and add an else: return statement.

```
if sys.modules.get("IPython") is None:
    return
else:
    return
```

When running without debugger the code does the same so I think that's ok. I don't get an error anymore with this change.

Comment: sounds good, I test it as soon as I can thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally resolve it.

I valid the answer of Andrej because he's method was good, directly modify the matplotlib files in the venv, but my file was a bit different from his one.

In my file, the code around line 1713 looked like this.

```
import IPython
ip = IPython.get_ipython()
if not ip:
    return
```

I simply replace it by this:

```
import IPython
if hasattr(IPython, "get_ipython"):
    ip = IPython.get_ipython()
else:
    return
if not ip:
    return
```

To make sure the function exist before to call it.

This was finally so simple, I was just scare to edit my venv by myself ^^.

Thx a lot